# Getting force close when getting the number from Contact lists

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have made a app in which user has to register all his details.For the contact info i have used a button ,when clicked opens the contact list.When user selects a particular contact, the number of that selected contact should be displayed in the edit text.But whenever i select a contact my app crashes

Code.

```
 private String strFirstName, strLastName, strEmail, strPassword, strConfirmPassword, strMobile, contactNumber;
    private Intent intent;
 case R.id.bt_contacts:
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                break;
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                if (number.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id,
                            null, null);
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                    contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    etMobile.setText(contactNumber);

                }
            }

            etMobile.setText("" + contactNumber);
        }
    }
```

Logcat

```
07-28 11:42:31.228  12387-12387/example.com.pocketdocs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/1135r974-27272727272727.3789r975-27272727272727/974 }} to activity {example.com.pocketdocs/example.com.pocketdocs.MainActivity.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3205)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.SignUp.SignUpFragment.onActivityResult(SignUpFragment.java:201)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5196)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3205)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: as you put check for cursor c if (c.moveToFirst()) you need to put check for cursor named phones. Issue is your cursor has no rows to iterate.

Comment: Can you tell us which line is number 201?

Comment: contactNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela means what to do sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

instead it should be

```
Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the log cat:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

You are trying to access something that does not exist. My guess would be that the Cursor returned is not pointing at anything. Thus c.moveToFirst() wont work, since there is no first element to point at. You could confirm this by using c.getCount();

Since you are requesting data with ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI you should also use that in your query:

```
Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: The cursor is not pointing at any contacts, Either you don't have any contacts or the call is made in the wrong way. Maybe you are running on an emulator with no contacts?

Comment: Have you added    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> to the manifest? See http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html for more info which contains a full, working guide how to retrieve contacts, this is solve your problem.

Comment: no sir i am using my cell phone to test the app and i am having many contacts

Comment: Then I would go though the android training (which i linked last comment). You could also try not starting a new acitivty and just fetch the contacts right away like done in this tutorial: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/provider/android-contacts-example/

Comment: Also I believe you using the  wrong key in your query replace ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI with ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI like this: Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

Comment: What was the problem? Wrong URI?